# Slow SELECT in Drupal CMS

Tags: mysql, performance, drupal, query-performance

I have a slow query from a table with 7000 rows.
After a long time trying to optimize the MySQL conf nothing has changed.
The query:

```
| 38 | root | localhost | nrj | Query | 28 | Sending data | 

SELECT node.nid AS nid, workflow_node_current.stamp AS workflow_node_current_stamp,
    'node' AS field_data_field_rh_username_node_entity_type,
    'node' AS field_data_field_text_no1_node_entity_type,
    'node' AS field_data_field_membership_number_node_entity_type,
    'node' AS field_data_field_text_1_255_n12_node_entity_type
FROM  node node
LEFT JOIN  workflow_node_history workflow_node_current ON 
    (SELECT max(hid)
     FROM workflow_node_history
     WHERE nid = node.nid AND sid != old_sid 
    ) = workflow_node_current.hid
WHERE (((node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN ('membership_request'))
      AND (workflow_node_current.sid = '85')))
ORDER BY workflow_node_current_stamp DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: Show the structure off the tables you can can the table structure with `show create table [table_name]`

Comment: Also provide explain plan of the query. Use explain keyword at the start of select statement to get explain plan

Answer (score 0):

Ouch!  I have never seen `ON ( SELECT ... ) = ...`.  Rewrite that somehow.

Perhaps more importantly, remove `LEFT`.  You are probably forcing the query start with `node`, even though it would be much faster to start with a subquery.

> sid != old_sid

Which column is in which table?  Please use short aliases for all references.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can check that you have adequate indexes.

Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` so we can see what the optimizer decided to do.